# How does MaterialApp fit in the inheritence diagram of Flutter?

Tags: flutter

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

This inheritance diagram is in the end of the above link:

```
Object > DiagnosticableTree > Widget > StatefulWidget > AppBar
```

Where does MaterialApp fit in?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html

> A convenience widget that wraps a number of widgets that are commonly required for material design applications. It builds upon a WidgetsApp by adding material-design specific functionality, such as AnimatedTheme and GridPaper.

Is it a parent class from which AppBar is derived?

Comment: You may be mixing class hierarchy (inheritance, extends) with widget hierarchy.

Comment: No, `AppBar` is not extended from `MaterialApp`. `AppBar` is a separate `StatefulWidget`. `MaterialApp` helps in setting (sort of) some ground rules for the app theming. For examples, a simple `Scaffold` or even an `AppBar` would need a `MaterialApp` somewhere in their upper hierarchy to get the theme details. Why? because these widgets are part of the `Material Design`, hence `MaterialApp`